# href Link to an element with a specified id within the page

Tags: jquery, html, href

I am trying to create some buttons to point to different areas withing the same page using ID's (href=#top) but everytime I click on such a link the default layout of my page is modified.

I have set a CSS value of "left:5%" for all the text within the page and this is gone after I click on a href=#id link.

The content for the main page is added dynamically using Jquery .load() in an article element and I think this is the main reason but I think it should work like this too.

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

Thank you,

Comment: I apologize but this is nearly impossible since I have so many files at this moment. I am trying to find the reason and I'll reply once I do. Do you have any idea if the "#top" or "#bottom" string that is added to the URL link can have any impact on my CSS code?

Comment: @Sid M If I disable and re-enable the "left:5%" from firebug it's back as it should be. This is getting a bit out of my hand since I cannot find the reason behind it. Are there any other methods to scroll down to a certain element without the href=#top link?

Comment: Hello, I have no idea what happened but I gave up. I used Jquery instead for a smoother scroll. If anybody stumbles upon the same issue the jquery code is $(".top").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#top").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});